# How do I map the JSON body of a GET request to a parameter?

Tags: ruby-grape, grape-api

I have the following definition in my endpoint:

```
params do
    requires :entities do
      requires :id, type: String
      optional :email, type: String
      optional :phone, type: String
    end
  end
  post "test" do

  end
```

Note this only works as a POST request and the following CURL will work:

```
curl -XPOST localhost/test 
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
     -H 'Accept: application/json' 
     -d '{ "entities": [{ "id": 3, "email": "test@abc.com" }] }'
```

However, the moment I change the declaration to get "test" instead of post, the corresponding curl request with -XGET no longer works due to the following validation error:

```
{"error":"entities is missing"}
```

If I remove the params requirements I can manually inspect the params hash at runtime and see that it only has a single key "route_info"

I'm currently using Grape 0.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because by specifying `-d` option you pass parameters in the body of the request while your endpoint is expecting them in the path as part of the url. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) why it's a bad idea to pass body parameters in a GET request.

However, can use that option but if combination with `-G`.

> -G, --get
>
> When  used,  this  option  will  make  all  data specified with -d, --data, --data-binary or --data-urlencode to be used in an HTTP GET request
>                 instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.

So that your `get` request by using `-d` would look like:

```
curl -XGET -G localhost/test 
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
     -H 'Accept: application/json' 
     -d '{ "entities": [{ "id": 3, "email": "test@abc.com" }] }'
```

Comment: Thanks for the link - makes sense. Incidentally, turns out that jQuery converts XHR get requests into query-string encoded variables too. I'll just use POST - I thought GET made sense semantically since it didn't change the state of the domain model and I don't want to be limited by URL-length issues, but alas